# Lack of analytic solution for a second order non-linear differential equation in the form $f''+c_1 f^2 = c_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

The following problem is from Bird Transport phenomena.

[image]

I have solved this problem and I know the solution. But one part got me interested, which I cannot prove the statement and that is the first sentence of part c.

Can you help about the proof of non-existence of analytical solution for the differential equation 3.K-1?

Answer (score 1):

Splution of $$f''+af^2=b$$ multiply by $2f'$ both sides to get
$$2f'f''(x)=-2af'f^2+2f'b \implies (f'^2)'=(-2f^2+2b) f'.$$
Integrate both sides w.r.t. $x$, to get
$$\int\frac{df'^2}{dx} dx=\int(-2af^2+2b)\frac{df}{dx} dx \implies f'^2=-\frac{2a}{3}f^3+2bf+A$$
$$\implies f'= \pm \sqrt{-2af^3+2bf+A} \implies \int \frac{df}{\sqrt{-2af^3+2bf+A}}=\pm\int dx+B.$$
The integral on the left relates to Elliptic integrals.

Comment: So there is no analytic solution for the integral, right?

Comment: Yes, Elliptic integral are standard but not friendly.